# XCode - /usr/sbin/chown error

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to make a build of my app.
It has worked before, but now I'm getting this error message which I have no clue about.

```
chown: MYDOMAIN\domain users: Invalid argument
Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1
```

How do I fix that without having to make another project as suggested in some forums?

Thank you,
Tee

Comment: What version of Xcode ? What version of Mac OS X ? Are you using version control ? What kind of Mac are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, there is a field under deployment called "Alternate install group" that you just have to set correctly.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: I found that setting, but it did not fix the problem for me. My correct group should be "SOMEDOMAIN\Domain Users" and chown does not like that one bit.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the above answer, set the Install Group and/or Alternate Install Group settings to a group you are a member of.

To find a group you are a member of, use the `groups` command in terminal.

As far as I can tell, you can safely change them both to 'everyone'.